# Inverse navigation on iOS

Tags: navigation, ios

I am designing an iOS mobile app where I have parent-child data sets. Imagine that you have a list view of objects (where you can do regular operations like add, delete or edit). When you tap on an object in the list, you can see the details view of the objects and you can take some actions.
I understand that if I want the user to see list view first then the detailed view, I would simply use a Navigation Bar like Settings or Inbox apps.
However, If I want to show the user the detailed view first, I am not sure what kind of navigation should I use in this case? Is there like an inverse hierarchal navigation that is commonly used?
I can think of adding both views in the same screen or adding a button in the detailed view that leads to the list view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While reading your question, I am wondering what *going back* or *home* means when the app starts by showing the detail view.

When opening a detail view from a list view, *back* would navigate to the list view.

If, however, I start in the detail view, I would expect the list view to be optionally accessible via some Catalog or Search (as you already propose). Or not al all, except via a main menu.

Apparently, to me, the detail view is *not* a child view when it is not accessed via the list view.